# Concerning the time when Esther must be read

Tags: calendar, megillat-esther, mishna, tractate-megillah

The first Mishnah in Tractate Megilla says:

> מגילה נקראת באחד עשר, בשנים עשר, בשלושה עשר, בארבעה עשר, ובחמישה עשר--לא פחות ולא יתר.
>
> The Megilla is read sometimes on the 11th, 12th, 13th, 14th, or on the 15th of the month Adar, neither earlier nor later.

Why did the first part not suffice and "neither earlier nor later" have to be added?

Comment: Whose translation is that?

Comment: @Scimonster IDK

Comment: Rashi says, "לא פחות ולא יותר - לא פחות מי"א ולא יותר מט"ו"... not that it wasn't obvious.  And I agree with what's implied by @Scimonster - the "sometimes" is a strange addition to the translation.

Comment: @Charles Koppelman right whats the ביאור to Rashi. An the addition is not strange see Rashi.

Comment: "An the addition is not strange see Rashi." - what do you mean by that?  The addition is not in Rashi, but in your translation.

Comment: @Charles Koppelman Rashi saids פעמים בזה ופעמים בזה!

Answer (score 1):

‘Can’t be later’ teaches us that if Shushan Purim falls out on shabbos, it is pushed back, not forward to Sunday (meseches Megillah daf 2a Rashi DH “chal arba’a Asar lehiyos b’erev shabbos”)